# Jquery Sortable Divs with Dynamic Input Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to sort these dynamic input fields and I would like to be able to drag them individually so they can be reordered. Right now when I run this code it is not treating the whole row as a div but each element of the div. What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Add or Remove text boxes with jQuery</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#main {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
  <h1>Add or Remove text boxes with jQuery</h1>
  <div class="my-form">
    <form role="form" method="post">
      <div class="text-box" id="text-box">
        <label for="box1">Box <span class="box-number">1</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="boxes[]" value="" id="box1" />
        <a class="add-box" href="#">Add More</a>
      </div>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.my-form .add-box').click(function() {
    var n = $('.text-box').length + 1;
    if (5 < n) {
      alert('Stop it!');
      return false;
    }
    var box_html = $('<div id="text-box" class="text-box" id="text-box"><label for="box' + n + '">Box <span class="box-number">' + n + '</span></label> <input type="text" name="boxes[]" value="" id="box' + n + '" /> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></div>');
    box_html.hide();
    $('.my-form .text-box:last').after(box_html);
    box_html.fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
  });

  $('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-box', function() {
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#FF6C6C');
    $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $(this).remove();
      $('.box-number').each(function(index) {
        $(this).text(index + 1);
      });
    });
    return false;
  });

  $('.my-form').on('click', '.text-box:last', function() {
    var n = $('.text-box').length + 1;
    if (5 < n) {
      alert('Stop it!');
      return false;
    }
    var box_html = $('<div id="text-box" class="text-box" id="text-box"><label for="box' + n + '">Box <span class="box-number">' + n + '</span></label> <input type="text" name="boxes[]" value="" id="box' + n + '" /> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></div>');
    box_html.hide();
    $('.my-form .text-box:last').after(box_html);
    box_html.fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
  });

  $(function() {
    $("#text-box").sortable({
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
      helper: 'clone'
    });
    $("#text-box").disableSelection();
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look through your HTML. Watch your indents, these help to keep things organized and readable for others. In any case, there is a rogue closing "</li>" tag hanging out on the same line as your "Add More" button. You should remove and see if this has any impact. 

Also, you don't need to wrap your submit button inside "p" tags.

Comment: Thanks sm1215. I figured out what it was. Here is a working example in jfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zjnne3cj/